# How should I store mainnet truffle artifacts?

Tags: contract-deployment, infura

Obviously, I shouldn't upload my private key or personal infura credentials to my repo, but I was wondering what was the best way to track main net truffle artifacts.

Generally speaking, for test nets I upload my test artifacts, would be a good idea to deploy to mainnet in a separate repo? What are the current best practises?

**Edit** The json file produced from running truffle migrate are what I am calling truffle artifacts.

Comment: Could you clarify meaning of `artifact` in your question? Is it truffle config?

Comment: The json file produced from running truffle migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For our Truffle based projects we use the tool [truffle-deploy-registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-deploy-registry).

The library allows you to store your deployed contract addresses in a networks config file separately from the Truffle artifacts.  You can commit the network configs to Git, and just re-generate the Truffle artifacts when you need to.

Full disclosure: I'm one of the authors of the library ;)

Answer (score 0):

`truffle migrate` does couple of steps:

1. **compile** - generates (non-specific for network) artifacts and put those in build directory
2. **deploy** - takes artifacts and deploys to specific network

> Would be a good idea to deploy to mainnet in a separate repo?

No. There are no differences in artifacts for different networks.

> What are the current best practices?

Do not store artifacts at all. Artifact is result of project's building. Usually the process is automated (CI/CD). Artifact should be built in pipeline. Code coverage should be 100% and all tests should be green.

Comment: I disagree with building artifacts in pipeline because it costs eth to deploy contracts and tracking artifacts in the repo allows you to deploy/test previous versions of the smart contracts. It can be really annoying to deal with. And getting 100% code coverage does not indicate that the smart contract is secure.

Comment: How often you re-deploy your contracts on mainnet? I think when you need to do, it starts smell, you simple loose trust if you change the contract permanently. `truffle migrate` is suitable for development, when you need to change contract often, but not on mainnet.

Comment: I would rarely re-deploy contract, but oftentimes my smart contracts are in the same repo as the front-end, so it is kinda annoying to figure out how to only conditionally deploy smart contracts in a CI pipeline.